# Wolfram Engine - how to list and terminate sessions?

Tags: python, free-wolfram-engine

Using WolframClient from Python (Jupyterlab notebook) I have at least one session - possibly more: there are three instances of WolframKernel running, possibly due to previously starting a new session without terminating the old session first (and reusing the session variable)

1. session.terminate() does not seem to do anything - a W.E. kernel calculation was started but, according to the (*) indicated beside the cell in the Jupyter notebook it has not completed; issuing session.terminate() also seems to have been queued because that cell is also marked as (*) (evaluating). Is there any way to kill the session from the Jupyter notebook or must I kill the kernel processes directly (task manager in Windows)?
2. For future reference, can one list the active sessions and refer to them individually in order to terminate them?
   Environment: Wolfram Engine (12.0) + WolframClient for Python; Python 3.7, Windows 10 64-bit Home